# network-related or instance-specific error when accessing database from a windows service

Tags: c#, sql, windows-services, connection-string

I want to perform some actions against a database from a custom windows service. The database is accessed through a reference to a Repository project. So, at one side i have the Service and at the other the Repository.

The problem is that i get a SqlException saying "a network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection" at the Windows Event Viewer log when starting the Service.

The answers that i've readed already suggests that it could be due to permissions problems, but i'm running the service with the same user that i use to access the database (windows authentication) and both the Service and the Repository project has the same ConnectionString, which is as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ViewMediaDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ViewMediaDBModel.csdl|res://*/ViewMediaDBModel.ssdl|res://*/ViewMediaDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=VIEWCAP\SQLEXPRESS12;initial catalog=ViewMediaDB;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:
(SOLUTION)**

The problem has gone... It was just that the connection to the database was corrupted (for some reason that i don't know)... After rebooting the system everything started to work fine.

Comment: Is the Service and the database on the same machine,  Might need to configure the Database for remote connections if not.

Comment: they are on the same machine

Comment: Have you tried using .\SQLEXPRESS12 instead of VIEWCAP.

Comment: what is the ServiceAccount type you're using?

Comment: Thank you all... It was just some extrange error solved after rebooting... Sorry